# Plugin Class does not get included in UE4 Build

Tags: c++, plugins, unreal-engine4

UE4 newbie here.

I've been working with some old code in my company lately, and I had to adjust an old UE4 plugin that takes care of some HTTP calls to our platform. Everything works fine in the Editor, but not in any sort of build.

I am currently trying to reference (or instantatiate, if missing) from a blueprint an Actor that is being defined in my c++ plugin, but no matter what I do, the class does not seem to exist in the build. I am currently using Unreal 4.21, and in the Editor everything works as intended, it's just the build.

I already followed [this guide](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/69663/runtime-plugin.html) but it didn't help, I haven't included the EnabledPlugins=YourPlugin just because I did not need it to be static. The plugin is in Engine/Plugins/Runtime, the manifest has set installed to true, and I've built the solution for the platform I'm building for. I am really lost, and any help would be appreciated!

These are the relevant logs:

```
[2019.11.05-19.47.41:442][  0]LogStreaming: Error: Couldn't find file for package /Script/DataLogger requested by async loading code. NameToLoad: /Script/DataLogger
[2019.11.05-19.47.41:442][  0]LogStreaming: Error: Found 1 dependent packages...
[2019.11.05-19.47.41:442][  0]LogStreaming: Error:   /Game/Blueprints/Tech/CustomGameInstance
[2019.11.05-19.47.41:446][  0]LogScript: Warning: Accessed None
CustomGameInstance_C /Engine/Transient.GameEngine_0:CustomGameInstance_C_0
Function /Game/Blueprints/Tech/CustomGameInstance.CustomGameInstance_C:SetPlayerData:0245
[2019.11.05-19.47.41:446][  0]LogScript: Warning: Script call stack:
Function /Game/Blueprints/Tech/CustomGameInstance.CustomGameInstance_C:ReceiveInit
Function /Game/Blueprints/Tech/CustomGameInstance.CustomGameInstance_C:ExecuteUbergraph_CustomGameInstance
Function /Game/Blueprints/Tech/CustomGameInstance.CustomGameInstance_C:SetPlayerData
```

And also, a few lines forward:

```
LogScript: Warning: UGameplayStatics::BeginSpawningActorFromClass: can not spawn an actor from a NULL class
```

Comment: i have the same issue on ue5 and can't find the solution. the posted solution by zod has not solved it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click your project executable and 'Generate visual studio project files' and then try again. Also you can open the project executable with notepad and check if the plugin folder is there.

If those don't work then sounds like your packaging settings need to be looked at since it works fine in editor. You can manually include folders to be bundled in your build, try checking the packaging settings and include the plugin folder.